# Drools: how to iterate list and add to another list

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I am trying to iterate a ArrayList and add to another ArrayList using jboss drools inside the rule.

I have a pojo with the list.

```
Class DroolsPojo{
   List<String> answers;

   //getters and setters
}
```

My pojo returning a list like {"a","b","c","","",""}. I want to iterate the list and want to add elements which are not equal to ""(not empty elements of the list).

How can I do this with drools?

Is there any way to get the element count which is not equal to "" with the drools.

My rule is like as follows.

```
rule "rule1"
when 
   dpojo:DroolsPojo(answers!=null)
then
    List list = dpojo.getAnswers();
    //want to iterate the list here
end
```

How to do this with drools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the rule just has to fire when the answers instance variable is not null?
Using dialect mvel, something like this should work:

```
package drools.xxx
dialect "mvel"

import drools.xxx.DroolsPojo

rule "rule1"
when 
    $dpojo : DroolsPojo(answers!=null)
    $answersWithoutEmptyStrings : List() from collect ( String(length > 0) from $dpojo.answers )
then
    insert($answersWithoutEmptyStrings)
end
```

Here I do the collect (iterating) in the when clause.

Comment: This is easy than writing inside then.

Answer (score 1):

On the right hand side you just write plain old Java code:

```
List list = dpojo.getAnswers();
for( Object obj: list ){
    String s = (String)obj;
    if( s.length() > 0 ){ ... }
}
```

The parser doesn't like generics (yet?) so you'll have to work around that.

Comment: I couldn't use for each loop. I used for loop and it is working.